# Retrieving an input value stored in a variable Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

If the value of an input is stored in a variable and the variable is declared in outside a function (global) and the value stored in variable retrieved from the function , it gives either give undefined or empty string BUT if variable is declared inside the function if works as intended

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <script>
    var a = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    function dis(){
      console.log(a);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="txt">
  <button onclick="dis()">Click</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, because the value of `a` was firstly evaluated at a time if it was declared outside the function. However, if it's inside, the value of `a` is re-evaluated after the function was called.

Comment: tysm that helped a lot

Answer (score 2):

The problem you seem to encounter is not one of scope but of timing: When you declare your variable `a` the input is still empty. So the result you get shown will also be empty. No matter what current contents the input field might hold at the time.

The following, modified, version should achieve what you wanted:

```js
var a = document.getElementById("txt")
    function dis(){
      console.log(a.value);
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt">
  <button onclick="dis()">Click</button>
```

Comment: tysm that helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

you should **update**  `a` every time `dis` called:
and make sure dom content is loaded.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    var a = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    });
    
    function dis(){
    a = document.getElementById("txt").value;
      console.log(a);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="txt">
  <button onclick="dis()">Click</button> 
</body>
</html>
```